# Python assignment to conditional LHS

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know about

```
a = val1 if condition else val2
```

but is there a way to do something like

```
a if condition else b = val
```

which throws a `SyntaxError` (which is understandable I suppose)

I would use a conditional,

```
if condition:
    a = val
else:
    b = val
```

but I hate having the same piece of code (here, the right-hand-side) in my program twice (in my real code, `val` is a non-trivial expression). I know I can just make a dummy variable to hold that piece, but that seems un-idiomatic.

It also occurred to me to do a tuple

```
ba = (b,a)
ba[bool(condition)] = val
b, a = ba
```

but that also seems very non-idiomatic.

Is there another way that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: `a,b = val,b if cond else a,val` is one line, but still repeats `val`.

Comment: It's a weird requirement. It is a better practice to assign the results of non-trivial expressions to variables that are named accordingly. E.g. topTenDebtCustomers or whatever. Then you can assign that value to "a" or "b" like you do in your if/else statement, which is the right way to do it. This is not a "dummy" variable and not un-idiomatic, quite the opposite. Your desire to eliminate well named variables to save a line of code makes you a BAD PROGRAMMER.

Comment: @aaa In the situation that made me ask this question, the meaning of `val` was completely determined by `condition`. So there is no semantically valid label for it (apart from something like `maybe_a_maybe_b`). It's a total corner case, but I was wondering what people thought the right way was. Of course, as is so often the case, I ended up taking an entirely different approach and not needing to do this at all. It could theoretically happen, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to encapsulate the logic and unpack it back to the variables you're interested in:

```
def decider(x, y, condition, val):
    if condition:
        return val, y
    return x, val

a, b = decider(a, b, cond, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. Make another variable to hold `val` and use `if`. Simple is good.

Answer (score 1):

It's *doable* in one line with tuples:

```
a,b = val if cond else a, val if not cond else b
```

But please don't use it, it's ugly and a lot more complicated that a plain `if` statement.

Comment: Very hacky but it works. Could be shortened to `(a,b) = (val, b) if condition else (a, val)`

Comment: Plus, you're repeating even more code. Now `cond` also appears twice.

Answer (score 0):

If `a` and `b`  have some previous values you can simply write:

```
a, b = (a, val) if condition else (val, b)
```

Else you can write

```
a, b = (None, val) if condition else (val, None)
```